# Is it possible to GROUP_CONCAT a result set as a new column?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have one result set in the format:

```
category name  description author
ABC      Lorem Ipsum       Dolor
DEF      Foo   Bar         Baz
```

I have a second result set in the format:

```
category product
ABC      Plane
DEF      Car
ABC      Boat
GHI      Truck
```

I would like the end result to look like the following:

```
category name  description author productlist
ABC      Lorem Ipsum       Dolor  "Plane, Boat"
DEF      Foo   Bar         Baz    "Car"
```

I have been trying to use GROUP_CONCAT on the second result set and joining it to the first result set by category to get the column `productlist`, but have not had success in creating the right query.

Is something like this possible?

I am using MariaDB.

Performance is not a major concern yet as the result sets tend to be small.

This is the closest I have gotten,

```
SELECT `NAME`, `description`, `author`, `category`, ProductList
FROM (long query) q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.product ORDER BY b.product SEPARATOR ', ') AS 
        ProductList, ObjectCategory FROM SOME_TABLE a, SOME_OTHER_TABLE b 
    WHERE ObjectCategory = 'ABC' ORDER BY product
) q2
ON q.category = q2.ObjectCategory
```

but the above only works for one hard-coded category at a time ("ABC" in the above case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, quite possible.  Aggregate *before* joining:

```
select r1.*, r2.product_list
from results1 r1 left join
     (select r2.category, group_concat(product) as product_list
      from results2 r2
      group by r2.category
     ) r2
     on r2.category = r1.category;
```